# Problem in a python program to find 2 digits happy numbers ( stuck in loop )

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I'm a beginner in python and I just wrote a program to find 2 digit [happy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number). we should give it a 2 digit number and then if it's a happy number it should print that it's a happy number and if it's not it should loop endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1.

this is my code :

```
input_number = int(input("Please Enter a positive 2 digits number\n"))

digits = [int(i) for i in str(input_number)]

while input_number != 1:
    for i in range(len(digits)):
        sum_of_squares = digits[i]**2 + digits[i-1]**2
        input_number = sum_of_squares
    print(input_number)
    if input_number == 1:
        print("Happy ;)")
        break
```

my problem is that my program never leaves the loop, for example 49 is a happy number, but when i enter it, it prints 97 endlessly. 
what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight variation to @joyal-mathew 's answer. This would work for any number of digits

```
input_number = int(input("Please Enter a positive number\n"))

while input_number != 1:
    digits = [int(i) for i in str(input_number)]
    digit_squares = [i*i for i in digits]
    sum_of_squares = sum(digit_squares)
    input_number = sum_of_squares
    print(input_number)
    iter_count+=1
    if input_number == 1:
        print("Happy ;)")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you , it works for any number of digits , i needed this

Comment: glad to help @Shah. If you think its the right solution, you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop you need to change the value of `digits`. Also since it's for 2 digit numbers you can just use list indices of 0 and 1.

```
input_number = input()

digits = [int(i) for i in input_number]
while input_number != 1:
    sum_of_squares = digits[0]**2 + digits[1]**2
    digits = [int(i) for i in str(sum_of_squares)]
    input_number = sum_of_squares
    print(input_number)
    if input_number == 1:
        print("Happy ;)")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive and verbose solution:

```
def is_happy(int_tc, seen = None):
    """checks if the number is a happy number"""
    if seen is None:
        seen = [int_tc]

    sum_squares = sum_of_squares_of_all_digits(seen[-1])

    if sum_squares == 1:
        return True
    elif sum_squares in seen: # check if the numbers are repeating infinitely
        return False
    else:
        seen.append(sum_squares)

    return is_happy(int_tc, seen)

def sum_of_squares_of_all_digits(number):
    """return sum of square of all digits"""
    return sum([digit ** 2 for digit in get_all_digits(number)])


def get_all_digits(number):
    """gets all the digits from the number right to left one bye one(yield)"""
    while(number > 0):
        yield number % 10
        number = (number - number % 10) / 10
```

Comment: I'm storing all the intermediate squares in list else the recursion will go on indefinitely if it's not a happy number, the un-happy numbers when sum-squared again and again repeat after a certain iteration.